# Align overflowing images centrally on page

Tags: html, css, image

How to align images on demo centrally?

with no overflow on x-axis on page.
i want images to be fully centered on page + it is important to know, that images are always wider that page. image has to overflow #wrap element, and be 100% wide on page.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <p>somecontent here</p>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/1000/500">

    <p>some more content here</p>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/1000/500">

    below goes footer

    <p>some footer text</p>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/1000/500">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:lightblue;
}
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/UD7jk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the images to be 100% of the page they should be outside the `wrap` div so you need to change your markup and use `wrap` only for content:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p>somecontent here</p>
</div>
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/1000/500" />
<div class="wrap">
    <p>some more content here</p>
</div>
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/1000/500" />
<div class="wrap">below goes footer
    <p>some footer text</p>
</div>
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/1000/500" />
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:lightblue;
}

body > img{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UD7jk/4/embedded/result/)**

Comment: is it the best solution?

Comment: or is there any other ways to do it, by leaving div with id "wrap"?

Comment: I believe that is as good as a CSS solution that you can get. You can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/UD7jk/5/ that implements some javascript code but I didn't find it to be 100% reliable in my tests

Answer (score -1):

If the images on the sides, you can hide, then:

```
#wrap {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden
}
```